# pandas DataFrame set value on boolean mask

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to set a number of different in a pandas DataFrame all to the same value. I thought I understood boolean indexing for pandas, but I haven't found any resources on this specific error.

```
import pandas as pd 
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3], 'B': ['a', 'b', 'f']})
mask = df.isin([1, 3, 12, 'a'])
df[mask] = 30
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
TypeError: Cannot do inplace boolean setting on mixed-types with a non np.nan value
```

Above, I want to replace all of the `True` entries in the mask with the value `30`.

I could do `df.replace` instead, but masking feels a bit more efficient and intuitive here. Can someone explain the error, and provide an efficient way to set all of the values?

Comment: Could you confirm whether my answer or JohnE's result is what you desired and update your question to clearly indicate this, thanks

Comment: Thanks, @EdChum. I wanted to set the `True` values in the mask and leave the `False` values the same. I edited the question for clarity.

Comment: No worries, I updated my answer, you just invert the mask to achieve what you want

Comment: Hey, your call but I didn't mean for you to switch the checkmark, just trying to clarify desired results.  I think @EdChums's answer is bit cleaner and more concise if you want to switch it back to his.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. They're both good answers. Sorry all!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can't use the boolean mask on mixed dtypes for this unfortunately, you can use pandas `where` to set the values:

```
In [59]:
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3], 'B': ['a', 'b', 'f']})
mask = df.isin([1, 3, 12, 'a'])
df = df.where(mask, other=30)
df

Out[59]:
    A   B
0   1   a
1  30  30
2   3  30
```

Note: that the above will fail if you do `inplace=True` in the `where` method, so `df.where(mask, other=30, inplace=True)` will raise:

> TypeError: Cannot do inplace boolean setting on mixed-types with a non
>   np.nan value

**EDIT**

OK, after a little misunderstanding you can still use `where` y just inverting the mask:

```
In [2]:    
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3], 'B': ['a', 'b', 'f']})
mask = df.isin([1, 3, 12, 'a'])
df.where(~mask, other=30)

Out[2]:
    A   B
0  30  30
1   2   b
2  30   f
```

Comment: Are the results right?  Should 30 be filled in for True or for False values?  It's the opposite of what I thought was asked for (although I could have it backwards) and it could be easily reversed by taking the complement of the mask.

Comment: @JohnE when you use `where`, the mask will produce the original values where the mask is `True`, the `other` value will used for where the mask is `False`, so the default for `other` is `NaN`, so it looks confusing but this is the expected and desired result

Comment: I agree that's how your code works and is supposed to, I'm just noting that it seems to be the opposite of what was asked for.  If you run the OP's code on just column A, for example, it produces `30 2 30`.

Comment: @JohnE yes this does seem ambiguous, I read his question as a way to replace `NaN` values but it reads more like your answer but the OP accepted my answer so it's unclear to me whether he wanted this result but asked for yours

Comment: Yep, no worries.  I just noticed we had exactly opposite results.  I think your approach is cleaner and upvoted it.

Comment: Is the double negation really needed? I want to set "everything at a mask" to a value. I should mask, and then set everything not-not at the mask to the value? Makes no sense to me.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to ***use different columns to create your mask***, you need to call the ***`values` property*** of the dataframe.

---

## Example

Let's say we want to, replace values in `A_1` and 'A_2' according to a mask in `B_1` and `B_2`. For example, replace those values in `A` (to 999) that corresponds to nulls in `B`.

The original dataframe:

```
   A_1  A_2  B_1  B_2
0    1    4    y    n
1    2    5    n  NaN
2    3    6  NaN  NaN
```

The desired dataframe

```
   A_1  A_2  B_1  B_2
0    1    4    y    n
1    2  999    n  NaN
2  999  999  NaN  NaN
```

The code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
     'A_1': [1, 2, 3], 
     'A_2': [4, 5, 6], 
     'B_1': ['y', 'n', np.nan], 
     'B_2': ['n', np.nan, np.nan]})

_mask = df[['B_1', 'B_2']].notnull().values
df[['A_1', 'A_2']] = df[['A_1','A_2']].where(_mask, other=999)



   A_1  A_2
0    1    4
1    2  999
2  999  999
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer. The .values property was exactly what I needed in order to make my mask work. Very much appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

I'm not 100% sure but I suspect the error message relates to the fact that there is not identical treatment of missing data across different dtypes.  Only float has NaN, but integers can be automatically converted to floats so it's not a problem there.  But it appears mixing number dtypes and object dtypes does not work so easily...

Regardless of that, you could get around it pretty easily with `np.where`:

```
df[:] = np.where( mask, 30, df ) 

    A   B
0  30  30
1   2   b
2  30   f
```

Answer (score 0):

`pandas` uses `NaN` to mark invalid or missing data and can be used across types, since your `DataFrame` as mixed int and string data types it will not accept the assignment to a single type (other than `NaN`) as this would create a mixed type (int and str) in `B` through an in-place assignment.

@JohnE method using `np.where` creates a new `DataFrame` in which the type of column `B` is an object not a string as in the initial example.